# Pythonic way to generate a list of list

Tags: python

What would be the most pythonic way of achieving the transformation from the following input:

```
 input = [('a', 1), ('a', 10), ('b', 244), ('c', 31) , ('c',45)]
```

to the desired output:

```
output = [[('a',1),('a',10)],[('c',31),('c',45)]]
```

where I have grouped in lists the tuples which have the same first element.

Feeling that Python has a strong potential (I'm new with it) in writing complicated things on one line, I have decided to use comprehensive lists. My initial try is something like:

```
output = [x for x in input if [k[0] for f in input].count(x[0])>1]
```

giving me a nice list of all my "pseudo" duplicates :

```
output = [('a',1),('a',10),('c',31),('c',45)]
```

which I further process to obtain my result.

My question is: is there a way to achieve this result in one line using comprehensive lists instead of two (ugly) steps?

Comment: 'b'is a unique element so I don't want it

Comment: @Lutz Horn : there is only 1 entry for b. AugBar wants collection whose entry is more than 1. so b is excluded.

Comment: You shouldn't name a variable input. You are overwriting the `input` function

Comment: That was just for the sake of demonstration

Comment: I made a performance comparison for suggested solutions, see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby` from `itertools` and list comprehension. This will give you a simple one liner:

```
from itertools import groupby

filter(lambda x: len(x)>1, [list(g) for i,g in groupby(input, key=lambda x: x[0])])
[[('a', 1), ('a', 10)], [('c', 31), ('c', 45)]]
```

Comment: how come downvote? the other previous answer are extremely long for a simple operation ...

Comment: Not me who downvoted, but he wanted to get rid of unique elements like b.

Comment: I used filter afterwards, cannot use if in the list comprehension due to the generator specificity ...

Answer (score 3):

Using a 1-liner list comprehension:

```
>>> L=[('a', 1), ('a', 10), ('b', 244), ('c', 31) , ('c',45)]
>>> [list(filter(lambda x:x[0]==i, L)) for i in set(map(lambda x:x[0], L)) if len(list(filter(lambda x:x[0]==i, L)))>1]
[[('a', 1), ('a', 10)], [('c', 31), ('c', 45)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). My solution is not one-liner, but more readable.

```
import itertools

lists_in = [('a', 1), ('a', 10), ('b', 244), ('c', 31) , ('c',45)]

lists_out = list()
for name, group in itertools.groupby(lists_in, key=lambda x:x[0]):
    l = list(group)
    if len(l) == 2:
        lists_out.extend(l)

print(lists_out)
# Output
[('a', 1), ('a', 10), ('c', 31), ('c', 45)]
```

Comment: I think he not looking for this

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the following:

```
input = [('a', 1), ('a', 10), ('b', 244), ('c', 31) , ('c',45)]

d = {}
for i in input:
  if i[0] in d:
    d[i[0]].append(i)
  else:
    d[i[0]] = [i]

print([d[k] for k in d if len(d[k]) > 1])
```

Don't forget, you have to mantain a balance between readability and cleverness.

**Later edit**: I actually gathered the other solutions from other answers and measured time execution (200000 uniformly distributed tuples with 'a'-'z' first element), see below:

```
# 0.048532 s
def foo(input):
  d = {}
  for i in input:
    if i[0] in d:
      d[i[0]].append(i)
    else:
      d[i[0]] = [i]

  return len(([d[k] for k in d if len(d[k]) > 1]))

# 1.9594 s
def foo2(input):
  [list(filter(lambda x:x[0]==i, input)) for i in set(map(lambda x:x[0], input)) if len(list(filter(lambda x:x[0]==i, input)))>1]

# 0.209639 s
def foo3(input):
  [filter(lambda x: len(x)>1, [list(g) for i,g in itertools.groupby(input, key=lambda x: x[0])])]

# 0.188625
def foo4(input):
  lists = list()
  for name, group in itertools.groupby(input, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    l = list(group)
    if len(l) == 2:
      lists.extend(l)

# didn't even finish, >120 s
def foo5(input_list):
  [[x for x in input_list if x[0]==a] for a in {x[0] for x in input_list if [k[0] for k in input].count(x[0])>1}]
```

So yes, more clever one-line solutions, but slower and harder to read are not really the "most pythonic".

Comment: Nice benchmark, I realize now that trying too hard to 'python' a solution might not be the best idea

Comment: @AugBar, squeezing code into one-line doesn't make it more pythonic. Read this about the zen of python "https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/"

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
>>> input_list = [('a', 1), ('a', 10), ('b', 244), ('c', 31) , ('c',45)]
>>> [[x for x in input_list if x[0]==a] for a in {x[0] for x in input_list if [k[0] for k in input].count(x[0])>1}]
```

will print

```
>>> [[('a', 1), ('a', 10)], [('c', 31), ('c', 45)]]
```

Comment: This is an incredibly slow solution.

Comment: Yet it is the only solution that is one line and uses nothing but comprehensions, the two requirements in the question.

Comment: Well, you're right. But I'd prefer 'the ugly' solution in 2 lines which at least finishes execution.

Comment: I would too, but the question specifically asks for it. The OP states that they already know the _two step_ solution to this.